# Why my static integer is not showing the changed value in the main function?

Tags: c++, recursion, static, fibonacci

Here is my code. Here `i` is the static integer as global integer. As I know here the value of i should be 8 for n = 4. But it is showing 0. May be there is some lack of knowledge in me. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

static int i;

int fib(int n){
    i++;
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n==1){
       return 1;
    }

    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"fib("<<n<<") = "<<fib(n)<<" calls = "<<i;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
fib(4) = 3 calls = 0
```

Comment: @carl  The value of I was calculated before the function call. Split this statement with std::cout into two statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your static integer has nothing to do with it. The problem is due to use of [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) / sequence points. The reason is that `i` gets evaluated first which at this point is equal to `0` and gets sent to output stream. Then the `fib(n)` function gets evaluated and sent to output stream. Break the expression into two statements instead:

```
std::cout << "fib(" << n << ") = " << fib(n);
std::cout << " calls = " << i;
```

This will ensure the the *proper* order of evaluation where `fib(n)` gets evaluated first and `i` gets evaluated second.

Comment: it worked for me! But can't understand what's wrong with the same line.
Anyway, Thank You .

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that in a statement like

```
cout<<"fib("<<n<<") = "<<fib(n)<<" calls = "<<i;
```

the output will be in the order you write it, but there is no guarantee for what order the computation of each expression will happen. In your example `i` is being calculated first, then `fib(n)`.

Try this instead

```
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int tmp = fib(n);
    cout<<"fib("<<n<<") = "<< tmp <<" calls = "<<i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value i is being read by << before fib(n) is called?

Never "do work" in a diagnostic.

Also you didn't initialise i to 0.

Comment: i is initialized by the compiler.

Comment: @Vlad, fair enough. Sadly my coding predates C99, so this is still on my hitlist.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your compiler is outdated.

As other answers explain, the compiler chooses to read `i`'s value before calling `fib(n)`. However, what they fail to tell is that the current C++ standard requires `i`'s value to be read after calling `fib(n)`. The program is already supposed to do exactly what you expect it to do.

According to [C++ compiler support - cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), the new evaluation rules have been implemented in GCC 7 and in Clang 4. You may either modify your code to be acceptable to older compilers, or switch to a more up-to-date compiler.

This is a C++17 feature, though, and the default is not to compile in C++17 mode. You might need to add `-std=c++17` or similar to your command-line options.

Comment: However, that is only mandated by c++17. If you don't compile with that option (or higher) you may not get the behaviour.

Comment: @GemTaylor Good call. For GCC, I thought this was also applied to older standards versions but I now think I may have misread. For clang, I didn't know one way or the other.

Comment: I'm not saying you won't get the behaviour, but some compiler writers may decide backward consistency is more important than lazy feature sharing.